# How to use current date variable to add new column in table?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i want to alter table add column with the current date and hour like below its not adding column but when i remove variable and make it simple text its add and please also inform me how to make this column name unique so that we not able to add same column again in mysql again

```
    //get current date 
            $cname = date("Ymdh");
            echo "v1" . $cname ;

    //add curent date column if yet not added 
        mysql_query("ALTER TABLE  groups_ids add " . $cname . "VARCHAR(35)") ;
```

Comment: `its not adding column` What error do you get? `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @webbiedave use this "  mysql_query("ALTER TABLE  groups_ids add " . $cname . "VARCHAR(35) or die(mysql_error()); ")  ;" but its doesn't show any error

Comment: Why would you want a column named with a specific date? It's hard to use with a query (you don't know the column name), and doesn't seem to make much sense. A column named `201204106` is pretty meaningless. Are you sure this is the best way to do things?

Comment: @Abdullah Adam: `mysql_query("ALTER TABLE groups_ids add " . $cname . "VARCHAR(35)") or die(mysql_error());` (your quotes are in the wrong place)

Comment: already correct it thanks dear for your effort and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the query you wrote. First you have escape the column name using a backtick (`), after that there is no space before the datatype

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE  groups_ids add `" . $cname . "` VARCHAR(35)") ;
                                                       //^ No space here
```

Comment: @AbdullahAdam, `ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD UNIQUE index_name (column_name);`

Comment: index_name <= where do i get this